# Convert .toBinaryString into its complement

Tags: java

I do not know why I am getting an error at the yy.charAt(i) assignments. It says... Variable Expected... Not value.

```
static int subtract(int x,int y)
{
    String yy=Integer.toBinaryString(y);
    System.out.println(yy);
    for(int i=0;i<yy.length();i++)
    {
        if(yy.charAt(i)==1)
        {
            yy.charAt(i)=0;
        }
        else
        {
            yy.charAt(i)
        }
    }
    int t=Integer.parseInt(yy);
    return(t);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign values to a string's index position, strings are immutable in Java. This will never work:

```
yy.charAt(i)=0;
```

If you need to modify a string, transform it to a `char[]` (using the `toCharArray()` method), modify the array and then build a new string from that array, using the `String(char[])` constructor.

Alternatively, you could use a `StringBuilder` to modify the characters before returning a new string.

Comment: close, yy.charAt(i) returns a value, effectively what the piece of code is doing is 'a' = 0 which is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder instead.

The code would be almost identical to what you have now, except for these changes:

```
StringBuilder yy = new StringBuilder(Integer.toBinaryString(y));
...
yy.setChatAt(i, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few things that are not clear to you.

- I think you mean the character '0' not the value 0.
- The lines `else { yy.charAt(i); }` have absolutely no effect. You can simply omit them.
- Strings are immutable in Java (i.e. they cannot be modified in place).
- Even if they were, you're syntax is wrong. Something of the form class_name.method_name() is a call to a method of a class. It returns a value that you can store, it is not the same as a variable and trying to assign to a method call makes no sense at all.

To modify Strings in Java, the best way is probably to use a StringBuilder. You create a new StringBuilder using your String, make the necessary changes on that and then convert it back into a String.

So this would look something like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(yy); // StringBuilder from yy.

// rest of your code here

builder.setCharAt(i, '0');

// more code

yy = StringBuilder.toString(); // convert it back to a String.
```

Notice that even in a StringBuilder you have to call the appropriate method and pass in the value that you want to assign to it.